# how do I restore the little folder on the right handside of the dock bar?

Tags: macos, dock

By mistake, I removed an icon that was on the dock bar on the right, which pointed to all recent files that were downloaded or screenshot'ed, etc, I would just click on that folder, and the recent files would appear. Is there a way to restore it? I tried dragging "Recents" from the Find window into the dock bar, but it gives something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the one like this, usually with a pop-up list of files

[image]

That's just your regular Downloads folder, inside your user folder.

[image]

Just drag it from there back to the dock, next to the Trash. The 'magic' popup behaviour will be automatically enabled.

If the appearance isn't how you remember it, try right clicking & changing the view/sort options

[image]

Comment: Super images and pop up description

Comment: It actually doesn't work. I dragged Downloads, and it opens very differently, and when I download something, it doesn't pop up. EDIT: Ah, I had to fix a few things in the settings of the icon, now it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Try the view/sort options. They may have reverted to defaults. Added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Open your home folder
- Drag downloads to the gap to the left of the trash / bin but to the right of the vertical bar (assuming your dock is still on the bottom of the screen)

You can always make a new account and log out of your current account and in to the new account to examine the default folders and see what is what. Log out of the new account and delete it when your back to your main account.

[Recents is a smart folder](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-or-change-a-smart-folder-on-mac-mchlp2804/mac) and not an ordinary file system  folder of files.

Answer (score 0):

To have "Recents" in Dock:

- in Finder select "Recents" and right click / tap with two fingers
- from pop-up window select "Add to Dock"

[image]